# Frame tap gesture xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I added a tap gesture in my frame when I tapped the frame it will focus on my picker. The problem is when I tapped on my frame the picker pop-up will display and when I click cancel the picker pop-up will display again. How can I fix this?

```
 <Frame StyleClass="fieldFrame" x:Name="OutletFrame" CornerRadius="4" BorderColor="#e8eaed" HasShadow="False">
     <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
         <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
     </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
     <local:CustomPicker x:Name="codePicker" SelectedIndexChanged="codePicker_SelectedIndexChanged" Unfocused="codePicker_Unfocused" ItemsSource="{Binding RetailerCode}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding DisplayText}" StyleClass="fieldForm" IsEnabled="False">
         <local:CustomPicker.FontFamily>
             <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                  <On Platform="Android" Value="HelveticaNeueLTPro-Lt.otf#HelveticaNeueLTPro-Lt"/>
             </OnPlatform>
          </local:CustomPicker.FontFamily>
      </local:CustomPicker>
 </Frame>

 private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(entRetailer.Text))
    {
       codePicker.Focus();
       codePicker.IsEnabled = false;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Skip the tap gesture and in your ViewModel add a `bool` property that controls whether the Picker is enabled or not.

In your XAML, add a `IsEnabled` binding:

```
<Picker x:Name="codePicker" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding RetailerCode}" 
        ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding DisplayText}"
        IsEnabled="{Binding CodePickerEnabled}" 
        ~~~
        />
```

In your VM, add a bool property that is true/false based upon your `entRetailer.Text` condition:

```
public bool CodePickerEnabled { get { return (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(entRetailer.Text)); } }
```

Comment: how can i do it in my code behind? I am not implementing MVVM yet

Comment: @LawrenceAgulto Add the `CodePickerEnabled` property to wherever you have your RetailerCode, DisplayText properties at.